# Excel: What is a formula for automatically inserting today's date as static value?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a form with 3 columns

```
Date          Item     Cost
10/feb/2022   pc       100
```

I want to enter the data by using the "Form" button which brings up a popup to easily create a new record but I don't want to manually enter today's date each time (only the time and cost). TODAY() of course doesn't work because on the next day all the previous dates will be changed to today's day.

The highlighted Date column should be automatically filled with today's date (11-feb-2002).

[image]

Comment: This built in Form doesn't allows Masking or any other,,, so that you can enter any DATE whether is Current, Past or Previous using Keyboard only,,, but VBA macro allows enter Date as Static to the cell !!

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to use data validation to effectively copy and paste-as-value the answer from =TODAY() into a cell automatically. Set one reference cell or named range equal to =NOW() or =TODAY() the value of which will auto update every time you edit a cell (i.e. every time the spreadsheet recalculates). Now set Data ribbon > Data Validation for the date entry cell, choose type *list* and refer to our reference cell. This gives a dropdown list with the current time/date reflecting as the only option in the dropdown. The time/date should be current to the most recently triggerd sheet recalculation. Once selected from the dropdown, it copies the time/date value into the data entry cell as value "locking" it in so that it no longer updates.

Now I am not sure if you can use data validation as part of the data entry form, but you can try. Else you must resort to entering data in the cells directly, or as per Rajesh's suggestion use VBA to code your own data entry form.